# Show date from DB in jQuery flot

Tags: jquery, flot

I have some data from the Db that I would like to show in a graph. This is data example - date and some number

```
[[2016-03-10, 4], [2016-03-11, 3], [2016-03-12, 6]]
```

Data in JS is taken from twig variable

```
 var searchFlot = '{{ flotSearch|raw }}';
 var barOptions = {
     series: {
         lines: {
             show: true,
             lineWidth: 2,
             fill: true,
             fillColor: {
                 colors: [{
                     opacity: 0.0
                 }, {
                     opacity: 0.0
                 }]
             }
         }
     },
     xaxis: {
         mode: "time",
         timeformat: "%Y-%m-%d",
         minTickSize: [1, "day"]
     },
     colors: ["#1ab394"],
     grid: {
         color: "#999999",
         hoverable: true,
         clickable: true,
         tickColor: "#D4D4D4",
         borderWidth:0
     },
     legend: {
         show: false
     },
     tooltip: true,
     tooltipOpts: {
         content: "x: %x, y: %y"
     }
 };
 $('document').ready(function() {
     $.plot($("#flot-search"), [{label: "Searches", data: searchFlot}], barOptions);
 });
```

It shows graph grid, but no data plotted on the graph. X-axis shows only 1970-01-01 label.

Comment: Short explanation: `2016-03-10` is the same as `2003` and is a timestamp about 2 seconds after midnight on 1970-01-01.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use timestamp format

```
var searchFlot = [[moment("2016-03-10"), 4], [moment("2016-03-11"), 3], [moment("2016-03-12"), 6]];
```

I used moment() in order to keep your dates

I added some code of mine because I recently did a very similar project, hope it helps.

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/q7hdch7n/)

Answer (score 1):

For your reference,

here is the flot.js document [flot google API.txt](https://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/API.txt)

According to this document,

You will find out that time series support in Flot is based on Javascript timestamps.

A Javascript timestamp is the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

So, you may try this :

```
new Date("2016-03-10").getTime();
```

Hope this helps!